# Computing q-expansions of weight-1 Eisenstein series

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, fourier-series, modular-forms

## Questions

I am having trouble understanding some details in the computation of the q-expansion of weight-1 Eisenstein series, as done in Section 4.8 of Diamond and Shurman's "A First Course in Modular Forms". My questions are the following, which are in fact Exercises 4.8.4(a) and 4.8.5.

**Why is $F_1^{v}$ well defined?** It is not clear to me that this is true. Since $Z_{\Lambda}$ is not periodic on the lattice $\Lambda$, this function actually depends on the representatives of $\omega_1/N + \Lambda$ and  $\omega_2/N + \Lambda$. I understand however, that as a function on $\tau=\omega_1/\omega_2$ (with $\tau\in\mathcal{H}$) it is well defined and weight-1 invariant under $\Gamma(N)$ (essentially because it is the function $g_1^{v}$).

**What happens with the term $\delta(c_v)(\pi i /N)$ in the q-expansion?** I am able to follow all the steps until equation (4.34), but it seems to me that this term is missing in the presented formula. I am wondering if I computed $\zeta^{d_v}(1)$ correctly, but this should be precisely $(\pi/N) \cot(\pi d_v/N)$ right?

The second question bothers me more as some calculations done afterwards to compute basis for $\mathcal{E}_1(\Gamma_1(N))$ and $\mathcal{E}_1(N,\chi)$ depend on the explicit formula for the q-expansion of $g_1^{v}$.

## Formulas

For those who don't have the book, here are some of the formulas I am referring to. These are the functions:

\begin{equation*}
Z_\Lambda(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{\omega \in \Lambda}(\frac{1}{z-\omega}+\frac{1}{\omega}+\frac{z}{\omega^2}),
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
Z_{\Lambda_\tau}(z) = \eta_2(\Lambda_\tau)z - \pi i \frac{1+e^{2\pi i z}}{1-e^{2\pi i z}} - 2\pi i \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{e^{2\pi i z}·q^n}{1-e^{2\pi i z}·q^n} - \frac{e^{-2\pi i z}·q^n}{1-e^{-2\pi i z}·q^n}\right), 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
F_1^{v}(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda, (\omega_1/N + \Lambda, \omega_2/N+\Lambda))=Z_\Lambda(\frac{c_v \omega_1 + d_v \omega_2}{N}) - \frac{c_v·\eta_1(\Lambda)+d_v·\eta_2(\Lambda)}{N},
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
g_1^{v}(\tau)=\frac{1}{N} Z_{\Lambda_\tau}(\frac{c_v \tau + d_v}{N}) - \frac{c_v·\eta_1(\Lambda)+d_v·\eta_2(\Lambda)}{N}.
\end{equation*}

These are some intermediate steps in computing the q-expansion of $g_1^{v}$ (here is where the term $\delta(c_v)(\pi i/N)$ appears).

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\eta_2(\Lambda_\tau)}{N} - \frac{c_v·\eta_1(\Lambda_\tau)+d_v·\eta_2(\Lambda_\tau)}{N^2}=\frac{2\pi i c_v}{N^2},
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
-\pi i \frac{1+e^{2\pi i z}}{1-e^{2\pi i z}} = \delta(c_v)\frac{\pi}{N}\cot(\frac{\pi d_v}{N}) + (1-\delta(c_v))\left(-\frac{\pi i}{N}+\frac{C_1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_N^{d_v m} q^{c_v m}\right),
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
-2\pi i \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{2\pi i z}·q^n}{1-e^{2\pi i z}·q^n} = \frac{C_1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^\infty(\sum_{m}\text{sgn}(m)\mu_N^{d_vm})·q_N^n-(1-\delta(c_v))·\frac{C_1}{N}·\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mu_N^{d_vm}·q_N^{c_vm},
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
2\pi i \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-2\pi i z}·q^n}{1-e^{-2\pi i z}·q^n} = \frac{C_1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^\infty(\sum_{m}\text{sgn}(m)\mu_N^{d_vm})·q_N^n,
\end{equation*}

where in the third equation $m$ runs through positive divisors of $n$ such that $n/m \equiv c_v$ modulo $N$, and in the fourth equation through negative divisors of $n$ satisfying the same condition.
Lastly, we have equation (4.34), which is,

\begin{equation*}
g_1^{v}(\tau) = G_1^v(\tau) - \frac{C_1}{N}(\frac{c_v}{N}-\frac{1}{2}),
\end{equation*}

where

\begin{equation*}
G_1^v(\tau) = \delta(c_v)\zeta^{d_v}(1)+\frac{C_1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sigma_0^v(n)q_N^n,
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\zeta^{d_v}(k)=\sum_{d\equiv d_v(N)}{d_v^{-k}},
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\sigma_{k}^{v}(n)=\sum_{m}\text{sgn}(d)d^{k}·\mu_N^{d_v m},
\end{equation*}

$d$ being non-zero zero in the second equation, and $m$ running through all divisors of $n$ (positive or negative) such that $n/m\equiv c_v$ modulo $N$. Also, $C_1=-2\pi i$.

Comment: Diamond and Shuman is a fantastic book overall, but these Eisenstein series computations aren't among the book's strong points. If you want to learn this material specifically, I would perhaps recommend consulting a different book with a more analytical flavour (e.g. the one by Miyake, or perhaps the more recent one by Cohen and Stromberg).

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thanks for your suggestions, I will have a look at these other books.